# Help in Ms-Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Need your help on the below. I have a table where I have functions and the individual function targets in min. & max.

**Table # 1:**
**Function`......`Level1`......`Level2**
A`..............`28`..........`29
B`..............`40`..........`45
C`..............`30`..........`34
D`..............`20`..........`25

**Requirements**

I have a raw data with lots of values, refer to Table # 2

**Table # 2:**
**Names`......`Function`......`Achieved Target`......`Attained Level**
Name 1`.........`A`................`28.0`................`None
Name 2`.........`A`................`29.0`................`Level 2
Name 3`.........`A`................`28.5`...............,`Level 1
Name 4`.........`B`................`41.5`...............,`Level 1

I have got the achieved Level i.e., Level 1 & Level 2 return using this formula which works without the function

`=IF(C18<MIN(C$5,D$5),"-",IF(C18>=MAX(C$5:D$5),$D$4,$C$4))` but what I now looking at is the matching of Function as the Achieved Level will depend on the individual function's targets.

For example, if we consider the Table # 2, we see that Name 1 belongs to function A and the person's achieved Target is below the Min then the level attained is 'none' where as for Name 2, the attained level for the same function will be Level 1 as he has exceeded the min but lower than max.

Appreciate your help. Sorry for using the dots to draw the table as it was quiet frustrating that one needs to have 10 points to post the image in the question which I find little weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example :

[image: Excel example]

The formula set in the D9:D12 cells is :

```
=INDEX($1:$1;1;IF(C9>=INDEX($A$2:$C$5;MATCH(B9;$A$2:$A$5;0);3);3;IF(C9>=INDEX($A$2:$C$5;MATCH(B9;$A$2:$A$5;0);2);2;4)))
```

If you need to generalize this solution, i would advise you to use [defined names](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefinedNames.aspx) instead of the matrix ranges such as $A$2:$C$5.

Hope that helps,

Regards,

Max

Comment: Thanks Max, but I am getting the error when I paste the formula and the error pointed by Excel is at INDEX($1:$1;

Comment: Did you try to copy paste my example. Does it work? i've uploaded my working example here: http://www.fileserve.com/file/QsAUR5z. Have a look.

Comment: hi max, yes I did copy your formula in the excel but still the same issue. The URL is blocked in my company so could not see.

Comment: @Yashman Gupta: depending on your version of Excel, you may have touse `,` (coma) instead of `;` (semicolon) in Excel formula. If you can fetch the file and open it on your system, it will convert the formula automatically

Comment: Thanks Max, it is working now when I replaced the ; with the ,